# Create Nested Sub documents/Sub Elements Using MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am stuck here. Basically, the requirement is to create a category with 4 levels of sub-category under it in one schema. This should be the approach

```
Category
|
--Sub Category 
  |
  ---Sub Sub-Category(Sub Category Level 1)
     |
     --------Sub Category Level 2
             |
             ------Sub Category Level 3
                   |
                    ------------ Sub Category Level 4
```

Image of schema structure for better understanding :

[image]

I have created till Category and Sub Category by creating a separate module and CURD data from one Schema.

I have the approach of creating another page for Sub Sub Category. But I think further it might get complicated. If anyone has a better approach please help me with the problem I am facing. Here is the data image from ROBOT 3T

My Robo 3T Example Of Data Category Insert :

[image]

My Robo 3T Example Of Data Sub - Category Insert :

[image]

Please Help me with a better and dynamic approach. Thank you. :)

Comment: What does the schema of sub categories looks like? How do they vary?

Comment: Thank You For the comment :)... Each category level should have detail information separate like a name title description and much more if required...

Comment: But do all these sub categories share same schema design? Why do you want to create separate modules for each sub category?

Comment: Instead of nesting each category you can just reference parent category id in each sub category. This way it will also be very easy to separate each category and also work with them individually

Comment: Yes, all subcategories share the same schema as per our current approach. because each sub-categories contains there Meta information. And as per users (Who are going to use) view it should be complicated for them. So we are thinking a separate module with one schema

Comment: See I think the best approach here is to create separate documents independent of each other and just reference the parent category in each document. This way you can structure the data after retrieving it from the database and also it will be easy to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: parent category id in each sub category in this approach we got to create seperate schema for each. Well, we used this approach and scraped it.

Comment: No why do you have to create separate schema? The category at the top will have null as parent id and rest of them will have that field. I dont see why you will have to work with different schemas

Comment: I have worked with a similar structure but way too complicated and using a tree structure to design the schema was not good at all. You will get into some serious issues if your sub categories increase more than just four levels. This is not at all a scalable solution and with four levels too you will find performing normal operations like updating deeper nested category quite challenging.

Comment: Point to be noted... it will be complicated but I think creating the separate document might create a performance issue. and we are also trying to avoid populate for this. But let's see how it will move.

Comment: See mongodb is designed for documents structure. So you can have like a million different documents but it will still work amazingly fast. You can read about it on the official website under schema design best practices. And also there is a 16mb document size limit in mongodb so if you increase fields in a single category in future and also increase number of sub categories you will eventually reach the 16 mb limit and then it will be a nightmare to deal with schema design changes. So please consider all these things before designing your structure. There is no such limits on collections.

Comment: Do take a look at this blog https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: Yes, you got a point. We will consider this point Thank you so much for blog reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution to this problem by using Embedded/Nested documents method in MongoDB.
What we use to do is when we found

I have created two modules for category and sub-category.
For category, I used to create the function.

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
let params= JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(req.body))
categoryModel
        .create(params)
        .then(success => {
           var data = {
              status: 200,
              message: "Record save successfully ",
              data: success
           };
           resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           reject(err);
        });
      })
```

For sub-category, I have used the update function by getting the id of the category(It depends how you do but it is important to get id to update).

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
let id = req.body.id;
let params = re

  categoryModel.update({ _id: id}, 
  { $set: { "sub_category.$.name": "sub_category1", 
          "sub_category.$.type": "video" } })
   .then(success => {
           var data = {
              status: 200,
              message: "Record save successfully ",
              data: success
           };
           resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           reject(err);
        });
     })
```